# calling non exported functions from dll using c++ console app

Tags: visual-c++

i have a dll with COM METHOD functions i want to call
i know the prototype and parameters of each fun. and also return type
can anyone help me in calling these functions in details please because i am a beginner in this part

i use vs2010

thanks in advance